# Parallelize loop over numpy rows

Tags: python, numpy, dask

I need to apply the same function onto every row in a numpy array and store the result again in a numpy array.

```
# states will contain results of function applied to a row in array
states = np.empty_like(array)

for i, ar in enumerate(array):
    states[i] = function(ar, *args)

# do some other stuff on states
```

`function` does some **non trivial** filtering of my data and returns an array when the conditions are True and when they are False. `function` can either be pure python or cython compiled. The filtering operations on the rows are complicated and can depend on previous values in the row, this means I can't operate on the whole array in an element-by-element fashion

Is there a way to do something like this in dask for example?

Comment: It still doesn't make sense.  Where is `i` coming from?  Are you trying to call `enumerate`?

Comment: Your function takes only current row or it can take any other row also?

Comment: The function accepts any 1D numpy array. It's doesn't care where that array came from.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Dask solution

You could do with with dask.array by chunking the array by row, calling `map_blocks`, then computing the result

```
ar = ...
x = da.from_array(ar, chunks=(1, arr.shape[1]))
x.map_blocks(function, *args)
states = x.compute()
```

By default this will use threads, you can use processes in the following way

```
from dask.multiprocessing import get
states = x.compute(get=get)
```

#### Pool solution

However dask is probably overkill for embarrassingly parallel computations like this, you could get by with a threadpool

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
pool = ThreadPool()

ar = ...
states = np.empty_like(array)

def f(i):
    states[i] = function(ar[i], *args)

pool.map(f, range(len(ar)))
```

And you could switch to processes with the following change

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
pool = Pool()
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn your function into a universal function: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html.

Then: `states = function(array, *args)`.

Comment: I can't operate on the array in an element-by-element fashion. The filtering of a single row depends on previous values.

Comment: @kain88: You don't use `i` properly in your for loop and you don't seem to pass it to the function.  It doesn't make any sense.