# How to use Dask to parallelize up a `sel()` operation in xarray?

Tags: python, dask, python-xarray

I have an array of values called `speed`, and I'm mapping it to another array of values of the same shape called `power` by looking up the nearest value in a lookup table `speed_to_power_lut`. This process takes about 2.5 seconds on my machine, and I want to speed it up.

```py
import time

import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

LON = np.arange(0, 360, 0.25)
LAT = np.arange(-90, 90, 0.25)
TIME = np.arange(0, 24)
speed = xr.DataArray(
    np.random.uniform(high=10, size=(len(LON), len(LAT), len(TIME))),
    coords={'lon': LON, 'lat': LAT, 'time': TIME})
speed_to_power_lut = xr.DataArray(
    np.random.uniform(high=100.0, size=(100,)),
    coords={'speed': np.arange(0, 10, 0.1)})

start = time.perf_counter()
power = speed_to_power_lut.sel(speed=speed, method='nearest')
print(f'Without chunk: {time.perf_counter() - start:.3f} s')

speed = speed.chunk({'lon': len(LON) // 16})

start = time.perf_counter()
power = speed_to_power_lut.sel(speed=speed, method='nearest')
print(f'With chunk:    {time.perf_counter() - start:.3f} s')
```

The [xarray documentation](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/dask.html#using-dask-with-xarray) suggests that, if I chunk the array, Dask will automatically be used under the hood to make things faster. Unfortunately, that's not what I'm seeing:

```
Without chunk: 2.477 s
With chunk:    2.499 s
```

I'm somewhat new to xarray and entirely new to Dask, so maybe I'm just missing something trivial. Or is this particular use case not parallelized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably that `speed_to_power_lut` is not an dask array. Anyway with how sel works here it seems to me that dask wouldn't help too much with this operation.

Have you considered something like this:

```
speed_to_power_lut = np.append(speed_to_power_lut.values, speed_to_power_lut.values[99])
index = (speed.round(1)*10).astype(int)
power = speed_to_power_lut[index]
```

It's very hacky in this case, but in general I think a lookup with numpy applied to the values in the xarray will be quicker than using this somewhat esoteric sel logic.

Comment: I'll give that a try, thanks! In fact that's how I originally intended the LUT to be used, but then I realized I could just use `sel` instead :) A simple lookup by integer index might indeed be (a lot) faster.

Comment: By the way, why would Dask not help here? Without it, the operation is single-threaded. Seems to me that each chunk can be looked up in the LUT completely independently of the others. Or is that not how `sel` is implemented?

Comment: That's a good question. I actually don't know how it is implemented. Anyway each chunk should be around a 100MB to a GB in size for dask to bring benefits. Lower than that and the scheduling would eat up any gain in performance.

Comment: Really? It's just 16 chunks, can't be that hard to schedule, and it can all be read from the same RAM on the same machine. If implemented properly, it's embarassingly parallel. I could even parallelize it manually using a Python thread pool, but I thought this sort of stuff was what Dask was invented for...

Comment: Unfortunately yes, basically if all your data comfortably fits into RAM, using NumPy or Numba will often be faster than using Dask. Dask really shines when scaling up into areas where the data does not fit into RAM. See here: https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/array-best-practices.html

Comment: The full quote is "If your data fits comfortably in RAM **and you are not performance bound**". But the answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32816410/parallelize-loop-over-numpy-rows suggests that my thread pool idea might not be so crazy after all.

Comment: If I use `speed_to_power_lut.chunk(chunks={})`, stack traces do show Dask being used, but I still only get utilization on a single CPU core, and the total process takes about 20 times _longer_. Using integer indexing, however, is about 11 times _faster_ which is great!